# How can I set date labels at every midnight for hourly data in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having an issue with plotting hourly data and showing day x-axis ticks. I want the date tick to be shown at 00:00, rather than 16:00.

I have two sets of datetime and value data shown as bar plots, using the following code:

```py
datetimes_a = [datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 23, 0)]
values_a = [0.1666666710128387, 0.3000000057121118, 0.15000000409781933, 0.1750000063329935, 0.17500000384946665, 0.1916666670391957, 0.699999988079071, 0.09999999735090467, 0.22500000521540642, 0.15000000161429247, 0.09166666865348816, 0.11666666654249032, 0.07500000298023224, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.23333333929379782]

datetimes_b = [datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 16, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 18, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 22, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 23, 0)]
values_b = [0.10000000335276127, 0.10000000024835269, 0.13333333594103655, 0.06666666828095913, 0.10000000211099784, 0.19000000432133674, 0.0, 0.26000000461935996, 0.13333333532015482, 0.09166666927436988, 0.18333333730697632, 0.15000000223517418, 0.15000000471870104, 0.3300000041723251, 0.3166666713853677, 0.2666666689846251, 0.21249999850988388, 0.15833333631356558]

ax.bar(datetimes_a, values_a, width=0.042, align="edge")
ax.bar(datetimes_b, values_b, width=0.042, align="edge")
```

I then format x-axis ticks as follows:

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("'%m/%d"))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))

plt.xticks(rotation=270)
```

The output is as follows (cropped):

[image: Date shown at 16:00]

How can I set correctly set the time the date tick is shown at to always be at 00:00?

---

EDIT: I can get it working using `matplotlib.ticker` with the major locator but it only works if the data starts at 00:00. See here:

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.IndexLocator(base=1, offset=0))
```

Data starting at midnight:

[image: 2021-12-01 00:00 to 2021-12-02 00:00]

Data starting at 1 AM (incorrect):

[image]

This is likely a very janky temporary solution and I would like the solution to work regardless of the start time. I guess I could take the first datetime object's hour value to set the offset some way.

Comment: Why not start at 00:00 and end at 00:00 by adding the following code? For a question like this, it would be difficult to answer without providing the actual time series data that is used. `ax.set_xlim(datetimes.index[0], datetimes.index[-1])`

Comment: I edited the question with some example data. The data can start at any hour and end at any hour however, not necessarily at 00:00. @r-beginners

Comment: Now that the question has been updated and the data has been provided, will adding the following code solve the problem? `ax.set_xlim(datetimes_a[0], datetimes_a[-1])`

Comment: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`. I think it's because it's datetime data?

Comment: This is a confirmation using your data provided to us. No errors have occurred in my environment.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was doing something silly. The code works, even when the first item isn't midnight.

Comment: I should add I used `ax.set_xlim(min(datetimes_a[0], datetimes_b[0]), max(datetimes_a[-1], datetimes_b[-1]))` so that if the data sets start and end at different times it'll still work

Comment: You're right about that.